# Expo router no popToTop/backToTop to go back to the root

Tags: react-native, navigation, expo, router

The newly released expo router https://expo.github.io/router/docs/features/linking#userouter provides a cool solution for handling navigation in react-native. However, while it implements `push`, `replace` and `back` there is no method as far as I can see to pop to the root like in other navigation library alternatives.

Example:
Image navigating like following
Home -> Contacts -> Contact
While at the contact page there is no way as far as I can see to navigate back to Home without using replace. However the problem with replace is that then users will be able to navigate back from home to Contact which makes no sense. Furthermore replace will animate Home as coming in from the right effectivly making it appear top in the stack.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution!

So the `useNavigation` hook actually seems to have all the same capabilities as the react-navigations counterpart. That means you can do `navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop())` where `StackActions` is imported from '@react-navigation/native' while `useNavigation` expo-router.

Taking this a step further the deep to @react-navigation can be completely omitted by dispatching `{ type: 'POP_TO_TOP' }`

CODE:

```html
import { useNavigation } from 'expo-router'

// In component
const navigation = useNavigation()

// In your function
navigation.dispatch({ type: 'POP_TO_TOP' })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be supported in expo-router as of today.

Answer (score 2):

From playing around, it seems you can just do a `router.push("/")`. Say you navigate from index to screenA to screenB. A `router.push("/")` in screenB will then result in navigating back to index. Calling `router.back()` inside index will then do nothing as there will be no screen to go back to.